# Dynamic CSS with PHP - Wordpress & Visual Composer Buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am creating a custom Visual Composer (WordPress plugin) element for buttons within my WordPress theme.

I have created colorpicker fields so that a user can change the background color / text color / background hover color / text hover color, etc.

Now the problem I am facing, is how on earth do I get a user's selection for say "a button's hover color" to update the CSS.

I understand that if I have a color in a variable I can do this:

```
<div style="background: <?php echo $users_bg_color ?>">
```

But how would I achieve this for :hover & :active fields. I obviously can't do this with inline styles, so do I need to update a CSS field dynamically? How should I do this? Or is there another, better alternative?

Teach me how to be a "big-boy" WordPress developer - please ._.

If someone can point me in the right direction, because I am baffled, I will be eternally grateful.

Thank-you

Comment: You need to use javascript to get the value and update the relevant elements.

Comment: You will HAVE to use JavaScript as well. It is possible entirely only with JavaScript too. Once the response is received the DOM has to change, you cannot do this with PHP

Comment: Thanks guys - makes perfect sense, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be thinking incorrectly here, but are you wondering how, once a user selects hover, active, etc, how to actually make that change appear on the site? If you mean instead that you'd like those changes to appear INSTANTLY as you select the color, then the commentors above are right -- that'd be some javascript. Otherwise, you could do something like this.. This is the method a lot of themes use, for better or worse:

In your theme's header.php, create a block of code like this:

```
<style>
  .button{background-color: <?php echo get_field('button_bg_color'); }
  .button:hover{background-color: <?php echo get_field('button_bg_hover_color'); 
  .button:active{background-color: <?php echo get_field('button_bg_active_color'); }
</style>
```

And so on.. And the actual function "get_field" is probably wrong, as that's what ACF uses, but you could plop in whatever function you've written that gets the values from your page builder.

Comment: Thanks Greg, that makes perfect sense. I think what I might do to save some headaches is create a section within Theme Options to choose global button styles, and allow user's to only select these colors for visual composer button's throughout the website. I'm just starting to think that it might be a pain in the ass to update buttons with different colors - maybe there's an easy way to append a unique ID to each button though - but meh. Cheers though appreciate your help.

Comment: Agree completely! This is actually how Salient (a pretty good, popular theme with a composer) works. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with CSS only,
Try this.

```
<div style="background: <?php echo $users_bg_color ?> " onmouseover="this.style.background='<?php echo $users_bg_color ?>'" onmouseout="this.style.background='<?php echo $users_hover_bg_color ?>'"> Sample text </div>
```

http://codepen.io/shoyebzz/pen/BLwwrz